# Expressions IF ELSE

Tags: reporting-services

```
=IIf(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 265, "Saturday", IIf(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 266, "Monday", IIf(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 267, "Wednesday")))
```

I am trying to write expression into a cell in my report [rdlc file] but I just couldn't achieve this. If the cell is equal to 265 then Saturday should display or if it is equals to 266 then "Monday" should show up. Can someone help me out with it please?

Comment: This looks like SSRS, not ASP.NET.

Comment: What is currently displaying?

Comment: @scott.korin, I just get exception saying Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘[BC40000] 'RequestMinimum' is obsolete: 'Assembly level declarative security is obsolete and is no longer enforced by the CLR by default. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.'.’.

Comment: For people who got here by google... the solution to the RequestMinimum exception is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244098/rdlc-making-call-to-obsolete-securityaction-enumeration

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The last `IIF` in the example code has `true` part specified. However, the `false` part isn't specified.

`=IIf(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 265, "Saturday", IIf(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 266, "Monday", IIf(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 267, "Wednesday", "????")))`

OR

`=Switch(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 265, "Saturday", Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 266, "Monday", Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value = 267, "Wednesday")`

Comment: +1 to shahkalpesh's Switch statement - or alternatively call custom code and use a select. Those IIfs are pains to write, not to mention maintain when you make a change in more than a couple of cells.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the set of available program flow options in SSRS expressions, with sequential values you can also use Choose:

```
=Choose(Fields!TarifeTipiNo.Value-264, "Saturday", "Monday", "Wednesday")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
=First(Fields!Shipping_Name.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")+environment.NewLine+iif((First(Fields!Shipping_Company.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")=""),"",First(Fields!Shipping_Company.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")+environment.NewLine)+First(Fields!Shipping_Address1.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")+environment.NewLine+First(Fields!Shipping_Address2.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")+environment.NewLine+First(Fields!Shipping_City.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")+","+First(Fields!Shipping_State.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")+" "+First(Fields!Shipping_Zip.Value, "DataSetForOrderEntry")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.